# Why can't I click the button to add a new user?

Tags: users

I want to ask you something. I tried to create a new user account on Ubuntu 12.04, but, when I am in the "User Accounts" window and I go left-down (where the "+" sign is), I can't click on it. It's not click-able.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must click on <kbd>Unlock</kbd> button in the upper-right corner first, enter your password, and then you can add/modify users.

[image]

Notice that after that, the <kbd>+</kbd> is now black and can be clicked, instead of gray:

[image]

Comment: it's done! :) God, my comment must be 15 characters long...