# Keep /home directory when installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS on my machine which currently has Mageia 4.1.

So, I have the following partitions: One for `/`, one for `swap` and one for `/home`.

I have some important data on `/home` which I wouldn't like to lose (I have backed them up, but I would prefer to keep them) after a clean install. I plan to reformat partitions one and two as above and keep the `/home` one.

Will I be able to tell Ubuntu to do so during an installation? By this I mean: Will it be able to recognize the `/home` partition and keep all its data intact while formatting the rest? And one more question: Will it be able to keep the users as they are our will I be forced to change them too? (I have the bad feeling that it won't be able to keep the users as they are...)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Keep the `/home` partition

#### Steps updated for Ubuntu 22.04

**Yes!** You can keep the existing home partition using one of the advanced installation options called **Something Else**

[image]

After choosing this option, you will be able to tell the installation process to use the existing `/` and `/home` partitions.

### Select the existing Ubuntu system partition `/`.

[image]

Click the <kbd>Change...</kbd> button below and make sure:

- The **Use as:** is `Ext4 journaling file system`
- The format partition box is checked
- The **Mount point:** is `/`

Once everything as set, click <kbd>OK</kbd>, you will see a warning popup message like:

[image]

Click Continue.

### Select the existing Ubuntu HOME partition `/home`.

Note the partition will not be marked as **Home**. Click the <kbd>Change...</kbd> button below and make sure:

- The **Use as:** is `Ext4 journaling file system`
- The format partition box is **NOT** checked
- The **Mount point:** is `/home`

[image]

Once everything as set, click <kbd>OK</kbd>, you will see a warning popup message like before.

The final **Install Type** window will look something like this:

[image]

Note:

- The system partition must have the mount point `/` and format box is checked.
- The Home partition must have the mount point `/home` and format box is **NOT** checked.

**Warning:** If the format box for the home partition is checked, you will lose all your personal files.

Once you are satisfied, click <kbd>Install Now</kbd> and continue as usual.

## Keeping the users

**Before you start the install process**

From inside the Mageia installation, run the follwoing command:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

This will give you the list of current usernames and user-numbers. Write the names and numbers down, as you will need them later when you recreate the users in Ubuntu. Thanks [Arronical](https://askubuntu.com/users/320386/arronical) for the comment.

**During installation**

During Ubuntu you will be prompted to create the first user. This user will have `sudo` privileges. This user is internally identified as user number 1000. Assuming that Mageia uses the same convention, you should use the same username you had before. Ubuntu will setup to use your existing `/home/username`.

**After installation**

For all other users, you will have to wait till after the installation. See [Why can't I click the button to add a new user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174588/why-cant-i-click-the-button-to-add-a-new-user) for details. If you create them in the same order as you did in Mageia, they will get user numbers in the same order as 1001, 1002, etc. Again, use the same usernames, and their existing home folders will be assigned to them. (You will be prompted to choose the existing folders or create new ones.)

## Cleaning up

Note: your home folder `/home/$USER` contains your data as well as configuration files (your preferences) for the applications you use. These are kept in hidden folders with names starting with a dot (.). Since configurations in Mageia may not always match that in Ubuntu, you may get some errors when running an application for the first time. If this happens, you may need to delete the corresponding folder (or file) with dot in the the beginning. Alternately, you may want to delete all the hidden folders and files inside your home folder to get a fresh start in terms of application configuration.

Also see [Changing to another distro: can the -home partition be kept?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41079/changing-to-another-distro-can-the-home-partition-be-kept)

Hope this helps

Comment: @Arronical Good point! I didn't need to do this, as I have only a handful of users, and I always add them in the same order. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: I'd add this important point: ***BACK UP YOUR DATA BEFORE STARTING!!!*** Although user68186's procedure *should* work without problems, an easy-to-make mistake could easily wipe out all your user data. Also, if you've got just a few users, my advice would be to create new users. Give them different usernames initially. You can change the usernames after installation so that they have the same usernames you like but use different home directories. That will avoid problems with application configuration files. You can then move your user data files and eventually delete the old home directories.

Comment: Thanks very much for the great guide!!! I have spread backed up my data but I am not sure whether my mail will integrate with Thunderbird automatically. I hope it does. Anyway I will try this today.

Comment: +1 to author and +1 to @RodSmith comment in my case when I was reinstalling once I also formated `/` though I had a seperate `/home` partition so as Rod Smith explained even after creating new user I just moved data from an old `/home` to the new one and deleted the old one.

Comment: "Make sure to choose to format / partition as ext4" , if the original / was already ext4,  is it necessary to format it and check the box for format?

Comment: @tim yes. Formatting ensures all the old versions of programs and general settings are gone and cannot conflict with the new stuff.

Comment: THanks. If not choosing format `/`, what will happen after installation? will the original content and the new content co-exist in `/`?

Comment: @tim Some will get overwritten. Some may conflict with other.

Comment: Keep the users is great, keep the users AND the groups is even better! Also one could do a copy of `/etc` to `/home/me-name/etc`  just for safe keeping. Or even better, put it on a USB stick so that you sure won't erase that one.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Good idea. Sometimes it is easier to pull up the old config from the old `/etc` folder than start from scratch.