# Malware Bruteforce Attack on software RAID server

Tags: security, raid, mdadm, malware

A month ago or so I wanted to make sure I still had access to my Linux box while away from home.  I did NOT take the time to properly harden the box and got some malware installed into the init scripts and crontabs.  I since removed the default gateway so it is unable to send dDOS attacks outbound.  Unfortunately I am also running mdadm on the box.  I have the OS (/) on md0 and all of my files on md1 (/home).  I want to blow away the OS partition but am worried it may effect my /home (md1) partition.  What is the best way to fix this issue (without losing my /home partition)?

Comment: in such a case I would use clonezilla to make a copy of the whole disk and each partition. Then you are on the safe side to return to any stage. You would need to boot from a Ubuntu live disk and start clonezilla from there. Use a USB HDD to store your backup.

Comment: In theory you can keep your data in HOME when you do a fresh install. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/630966/keep-home-directory-when-installing-ubuntu-14-04 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation. In practice it is best to back up your data just in case =0

Comment: @CatMan - Clonezilla does not support RAID so wont work.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to think that the removal of one (RAID) block device will affect another. You can safely remove the system volume and keep the one with `/home` on it.

It's possible that the new Ubuntu installation won't pick up the old RAID configuration by itself in which case you need to do that manually after installation.