# How can I take a '/home' on its own partition, and use it after distribution upgrade?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, 22.04, home-directory

Current: 20.04 with /home on its own partition.

Target: Install 22.04 on '/', and then switch the (then-new) 'home' subdir, to utilize the separately-partitioned /home.

My concern includes user names & ID #'s, group names & ID #'s... meaning, a new 'home' subdir with the installation user name will likely be ID # 1000. But on the partitioned /home, there is already an important user name with ID # 1000.

It is critical I keep the partitioned /home intact.  How can I incorporate that into a fresh install of 22.04?   Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep /home directory when installing Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630966/keep-home-directory-when-installing-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Don't forget to backup your home partition before you try anything in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @user68186:  Appreciated...  The backup will run tomorrow, then I'll do more prep, and re-study the link you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the install:

Preserve `cron`, `batch` and `at` jobs. Look in `/var/spool/`.

Preserve copies of locally modified files in the `/etc` directory tree.

Preserve locally installed applications. Save the configuration files, be ready to reinstall current versions of applications.

`apt changelog packagename` is your friend.

Everything outside `/home` will be destroyed by the install.

For  `/home`:

You can tell the installer (the "Something Else" choice?) to put `/home` where you have it, and UNCheck the box in the "Format" column. Verify. **DO NOT FORMAT /home**.

For the UIDs - keep copies of `/etc/{passwd,shadow,group,gshadow}`. Understand these files! Read `man -a passwd;man shadow group getent`

Let the installer create a `temporary` userid, UID 1000, homedir `/home/temporary`.

After the install,  login as `temporary`.

First, in one window, `sudo bash`. This is your Emergency Investigation and Recovery Window.

In another window, `sudo bash`.

Make another, separate backup copy of `/etc/{passwd,shadow,group,gshadow}`

Use your **original** copies to restore your groups and userids. Do NOT blindly copy the old files, think carefully about each entry.

Note that (`passwd` and `shadow`) and (`group` and `gshadow`) entries should be updated in pairs, both or neither.

Use `getent` to check your work. E.g. `getent passwd special`

Only after testing:

- login by the special user?
- can the special user still special?
- login by your admin user?
- can admin still `sudo`?
- ...

Can you log out. Then, log in as your admin account, and delete the `temporary` user. Read `man deluser`.

Comment: Your comments were substantially helpful.  After a failed "do-release-upgrade" for 20.04 -> 22.04, I did a new install of the latter (Cinnamon).  At one point I jazzed up the passwords, but did hold-shift during boot to get into GRUB, and chose a different (emergency) kernel to allow password fix.  I still have not solved a displayed GROUP shown as a numeric '1004' rather that what I wanted 'bigfish'.  That was remedied by using the add group command.  So far pgms tested have found their config and even migrated data (incl Thunderbird !!!).  MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.